# ¿Cómo puedo guardar un arraymultidimensional con una función en un .json con php

Tags: php, javascript, json

Buenas, quiero obtener con la siguiente función la data con formato json y guardarla en un archivo .json, esta es la función

```
function get_foreach_videos($data) {
  foreach($data['videos'] as $video) {
    unset($video['icon']);
    unset($video['tags']);
    $videoData[] = $video;
    }
  return $videoData;
}
```

la data que no me devuelve como quiero es con una estructura parecida a esta

```
"lessons": [
    {
      "title": "Lección 1: Introducción",
      "videos": [
        {
          "title": "Cómo y Dónde Arrancar - Parte 1",
          "desc": "Primero lo primero: Antes de comenzar a ingresar transacciones debemos ingresar los saldos iniciales de cuentas por cobrar, cuentas por pagar, inventario y efectivo (incluyendo créditos)",
          "lang": "es",
          "id": "61xx5xK9hTM",
          "next": "v5qQ8-xtFEw",
          "icon": "1"
        },
```

solo quiero la data del array video en un array, pero me devuelve algo así

> [[{}]], .

quiero algo así

> [{}],

gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Mejora tu pregunta añadiendo ejemplos de tu arreglo $data para poder apreciar mejor el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Disculpa si he improvisado un poco pero la estructura que has facilitado no me quedaba muy clara, aqui te dejo un fragmento de codigo que te devuelve algo del tipo [{}]. La function tal como la tienes planteada esta bien, no se porque no te devolvia el resultado esperado. Tal vez el input no era correcto, o el formato de los datos

```
<?php

function get_foreach_videos($data) {
  foreach($data['videos'] as $video) {
    unset($video['icons']);
    unset($video['tags']);
    $videoData[] = $video;
    }
  return $videoData;
}

$dataString = '{
  "lessons": [{
    "title": "Lección 1: Introducción",
    "videos": [{
      "title": "Cómo y Dónde Arrancar - Parte 1",
      "desc": "Primero lo primero: Antes de comenzar a ingresar transacciones debemos ingresar los saldos iniciales de cuentas por cobrar, cuentas por pagar, inventario y efectivo (incluyendo créditos)",
      "lang": "es",
      "id": "61xx5xK9hTM",
      "next": "v5qQ8-xtFEw",
      "icon": "1"
    },{
      "title": "Cómo y Dónde Arrancar - Parte 1",
      "desc": "Primero lo primero: Antes de comenzar a ingresar transacciones debemos ingresar los saldos iniciales de cuentas por cobrar, cuentas por pagar, inventario y efectivo (incluyendo créditos)",
      "lang": "es",
      "id": "61xx5xK9hTM",
      "next": "v5qQ8-xtFEw",
      "icon": "1"
    }]
  }]
}';

//Los objetos devueltos son convertidos a arrays asociativos, es decir
//puedes hacer $data['lessons'] en lugar de $data->lessons
$data = json_decode($dataString,true);

//Para que tu function pueda ejecutarse debes pasarle un objeto que tenga
//una propiedad videos, es decir un objeto lesson.
foreach($data['lessons'] as $lesson){
  $result =  get_foreach_videos($lesson);
  echo json_encode($result);
}
```